# Why does running UIAutomation methods from KIF result in: "UIAutomation is not enabled on this device. UIAutomation must be enabled in Settings"?

Tags: ios-ui-automation, kif, kif-framework

**Using:**
iOS 8.4, XCode 6.4, KIF 3.2.1 (https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF)

**I encounter the following problem on a real device:**
While running a KIF test case, calling the method, "deactivateAppForDuration" results in the following output seen in the XCode console: "*UIAutomation is not enabled on this device. UIAutomation must be enabled in Settings.*"

On the simulator, the app does indeed go to the background for the duration specified in the parameter of that method call.

- I can confirm that the setting in device settings, "Developer >
  UIAutomation" is toggled on.
- The build that I am compiling and running is a Debug build and is
  signed with my Developer Provisioning Profile (not a distribution
  profile).
- All the possible compile configurations in the scheme are
  set to debug (profile for example)
- I can record and playback UI interactions in the instruments
  developer tool (confirms that the app is built right and that the
  phone settings are correct)

**Specific Code:**
`[tester deactivateAppForDuration:5];`

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with `UIAutomation` on the device, see [here](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/issues/707).